# schedule kubernetes pods on different physical server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In my cluster there are 30 VMs which are located in 3 different physical servers. I want to deploy different replicas of each workload on different physical server.
I know I can use podAntiAffinity to deploy replicas on different VMs but I cant find any way to guarantee spread replication on different physical server.

I want to know is there any way to solve this challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you gave the answer ;)

I went to the Kubernetes Patterns book (PDF available for free in [here](https://k8spatterns.io/)) to see if there was something related to that over there, and found exactly that:

> To express how Pods should be spread to achieve high availability, or be packed and co-located together to improve latency, Pod affinity and antiaffinity can be used.

> Node affinity works at node granularity, but Pod affinity is not limited to nodes and
> can express rules at multiple topology levels. Using the topologyKey field, and the
> matching labels, it is possible to enforce more fine-grained rules, which combine
> rules on domains like node, rack, cloud provider zone, and region [...]

I really like the k8s docs as well, they are super complete and full of examples, so maybe you can get some ideas from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity). I think the main idea will be to create your own affinity/antiaffinity rule.

----------------------------------- **EDIT** -----------------------------------

There is a new feature within k8s version 1.18 that may be a better solution.

It's called: [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/):

> You can use topology spread constraints to control how Pods are spread across your cluster among failure-domains such as regions, zones, nodes, and other user-defined topology domains. This can help to achieve high availability as well as efficient resource utilization.

Comment: thank you. you mean I should add zone as label key and after that using podAntiaffinity with that kay. does it true?

Comment: Exactly... Defining an antiaffinity rule to avoid 2 pods running on the same zone would solve.

Comment: @hosseinbazrafkan take a look into my edit, I believe it will be a better solution for your case.